# Handle multiple NgbPagination in single page

Tags: html, css, angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap

I need to have multiple NgbPagination component in single page.

Reference:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples

I tried using id. But it didn't work. Changing one value in first pagination affects both the table.

Pagination1:

```
<ngb-pagination id="page1" [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [boundaryLinks]="true">
      <ng-template ngbPaginationFirst>First</ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPaginationLast>Last</ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>Prev</ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>Next</ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPaginationEllipsis>...</ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbPaginationNumber let-page>{{ page }}</ng-template>
  </ngb-pagination>
```

Pagination2:

```
<ngb-pagination id="page2"  [collectionSize]="collectionSizeb" [(page)]="pageb" [pageSize]="pageSizeb">
  </ngb-pagination>
```

Please let me know how to implement multiple NgbPagination in a single page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use muliple paginations on a single page. Its important to set the page variable for each pagination. Please see my [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rp8ct)

In your component:

```
page1 = 1;
page2 = 1;
```

In your components html:

```
<ngb-pagination id="page1" [collectionSize]="50" [(page)]="page1" [pageSize]="10" [boundaryLinks]="true">
    <ng-template ngbPaginationFirst>First</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPaginationLast>Last</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>Prev</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>Next</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPaginationEllipsis>...</ng-template>
</ngb-pagination>

<ngb-pagination id="page2" [collectionSize]="50" [(page)]="page2" [pageSize]="10">
</ngb-pagination>
```